SSRS 2022: An error occurred when invoking the authorization extension
I have a problem with accessing several folders in SSRS web portal. When I try to view more info about folder I get an error: An error occurred when invoking the authorization extension.
I tried to check the permission levels by going to Home -> Manage -> Security, but the security settings folder is empty.
I checked permissions through ReportServer database, and I have all required permissions.
What can I do to resolve this problem?
